# Converting html elements in json without using react packages and dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a json object which contains html tags in it.I have understood the disadvantage of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML and trying to use parse/stringify instead of it.But I could't convert the object to html tags.I'm not allowed to use any other react packages. So, is there any solution ?

```js
[
  {
    "category": "Chapter",
    "results": [
      {
        "content": "that <em>cultural</em> tool you donâ€™t do a good job of it. From this perspective, <em>culture</em>",
        "id": "4c00-b7f6-d6e0e252ae9e"
      },
      {
        "content": "sample <em>culture</em>",
        "id": "4c00-b7f6-d6e0e252ae9e"
      }    
      
    ]
  },
 
  {
    "category": "Learning Objectives",
    "results": [
      {
        "content": " <em>culture</em> is a communication.",
        "id": "4c00-b7f6-d6e0e252ae9e"
      },
      {
        "content": "sample <em>culture</em> which",
        "id": "4c00-b7f6-d6e0e252ae9e"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

```html
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Result = ({ data, onSearchResultClick }) => (<div >
  {
    data.map((category, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <div key={index}>{category.category}</div>
        <hr />
        <div className="searchShowData" >
          {
              category.results.map((result, resultIndex) => (
                <p
                  key={resultIndex}
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: (result.content) }}
                  onClick={() => onResultClick(result.id, result.type)}
                />
              ))
            }
        </div>
      </div>
    ))
  }
</div>);

Result.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSearchResultClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Result;
```

Comment: Plain DOM wrapping in a div and getElementsByTagName or nodes?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get your question.

Comment: And why you hate using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML ` ?

Comment: Sometimes if we get img tags or any other tags in that case using dangersoulySetInnerHTml is a problem.Also,I'm trying to find a alternative solution to fix this.

Comment: `componentWillMount: function(){
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = matchedFields.title;
  let someText = div.querySelector('em').innerHTML; 
}`

Comment: I'm new to react,Can you please update in my codes.I'm using a const, Can I pass willmount to it ?

Comment: The syntax of your data array seams to be wrong. It's also not clear what you are asking, I cannot see, where in you are trying to render the content of the data array.. please update your code, to make it clear, so others can help you. Thanks

Comment: Updated  the question.